# Assignment operator issue

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

hello people I've been studying about copy constructors for a while and I encountered this sentence in one of the sites:

*When the bitwise(assignment operator) assignment is performed both the object shares the same memory location and changes in one object reflect in another object.*
so later i tried to examine it and see if it's like that i wrote some simple codes as below:

```
class Base{

public:

Base(int age, string name) :age(age), name(name) {};
Base() {};
void display() {
    cout << age;
}
int age;
string name;
```

};

int main() {

```
Base b1(5, "Alek"),b2;

b2 = b1;

b1.display();

b2.age = 10;

b1.display();

system("pause");
```

so based on what is written up there the second call of *b1.display()* must have the value of 10 ? but why does it still show the same result?

Comment: `b2` is a copy of `b1`. Changes to one are not reflected in the other.

Comment: I expect what you read is talking about a situation where one object has a pointer to another object, In that situation you can get two objects having the same pointer to another object. But your code isn't like that.

Comment: this is the site that I'm reffering to it doesn't say anything about one object pointing to another if that was the case It wasn't hard on me to learn it.:https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-copy-constructor-and-assignment-operator.html

Answer (score 0):

Copy constructors work by copying all of the values of one object into another object.

Using your Base class, all of the member variables are are copied into `b2` when the copy constructor is called.

The only trouble comes up when the class has pointers.
Consider replacing `int age;` with `int* age;`
When the copy constructor is called, b2's age variable will point to the same memory as b1's age variable.

The pointer itself if copied, but not the dynamic memory data stored where at the location of the pointer.

Comment: b2 = b1; before i call this life of code both objects are defined so it's not copy constructed that is doing the job.check the site I've given in the comment aobve it's also stated there.